# Plotting Complex Numbers in Python?

Tags: python, graph, fractals, complex-numbers

For a math fair project I want to make a program that will generate a Julia set fractal. To do this i need to plot complex numbers on a graph. Does anyone know how to do this? Remember I am using complex numbers, not regular coordinates. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You could plot the real portion of the number along the X axis and plot the imaginary portion of the number along the Y axis. Plot the corresponding pixel with whatever color makes sense for the output of the Julia function for that point.

Answer (score 0):

Julia set renderings are generally 2D color plots, with `[x y]` representing a complex starting point and the color usually representing an iteration count.